# Defining a class parent with same methods but different constructors in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, object, oop, inheritance

I have this code:

```
class A {
    constructor(
        private _a: number,
    ) {}

    method1() {}
    method2() {}
}

class B {
    constructor(
        private _b: number,
    ) {}

    method1() {}
    method2() {}
}

class C {
    constructor(
        private _c: number,
    ) {}

    method1() {}
    method2() {}
}

let list = [new A(1), new B(2), new C(3)];
list.forEach((element: any) => {
    element.method1();
})
```

I have these three classes with different constructors and methods with the same name.

How do i replace the `any` type for typescript to know that method1 exists?

Comment: [Nothing](https://tsplay.dev/Wyq52W)? [`A | B | C`](https://tsplay.dev/W4jpaN)? [Extract an interface](https://tsplay.dev/NaE0nN)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically it was already in comments, but since the answer is absent: the most straightforward way is to create a new type:

```js
class A {
    constructor(
        private _a: number,
    ) {}

    public commonMethod() {
      console.log("A")
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(
        private _b: number,
    ) {}

    public commonMethod() {
      console.log("B")
    }
}

class C {
    constructor(
        private _c: number,
    ) {}

    public commonMethod() {
      console.log("C")
    }
}

type letters = A | B | C

let list = [new A(1), new B(2), new C(3)];
list.forEach((element: letters) => {
    element.commonMethod();
})
```